# Unable to return value from async method in typescript

Tags: typescript, async-await, protractor

I am working on typescript.I am trying to return a value from the async method.However , it always returns {}. Below is what I coded.

```
    async returnNewUrlAfterClickingLink(): Promise<string> {
    const allHandles = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
    await browser.switchTo().window(allHandles[2]);
    const cur_url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
    console.log("url is" + cur_url);
    return cur_url;
}
```

However I am able to log the url correctly.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the function? can you post the code where you are calling the function?

Comment: We'll need a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry I did not post the calling function. However Xotabu4 answered my question. I was not using await in the calling function. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Your `returnNewUrlAfterClickingLink` is marked as async, so it always return promise now. In order to get this value, you need to `await` result of this function:

```
const url = await returnNewUrlAfterClickingLink()
console.log(url)
```

And again - to use await your function must be set async, so whole call stack must be async/await.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Liam you are right. For tests that will mean to have chains of `.then` which might be pretty hard to read and write. So i personally prefer to put async/await everywhere

Comment: @Liam In webdriver tests it is basically 99% of your test commands to the browser are sequential by their nature and must be run in strict order. Unsynchronized code is almost never used for this kind of tests.

Comment: ah, I didn't notice the protractor tag